# Android Как получить список контактов "Избранное"

Tags: android

Получаю список всех контактов с помощью Intent.

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    pickIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1);
```

Так получаю все контакты. А как можно получить только избранные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.UI.LIST_STARRED_ACTION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Решение не моё. Нашел [ЗДЕСЬ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116147/intent-uri-to-go-to-favorite-contacts).